# NPM install from branch fetching master, not branch

Tags: node.js, git, npm, ssh, bitbucket

I have a plugin for my app on my own repo since I couldn't get the changes on the actual live repo. I used to be able to run the following to get it to install from the branch:

```
npm i --save git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/username/plugin.git#angular-4
```

Now when running this it just installs master, and not the branch. I have also tried using `--nofetch` which does the same thing, grabs master.

Any ideas how I could get this installed from my branch?